# Xcode's yellow warning underlines going crazy, making projects difficult to read

Tags: xcode

Xcode underlines potential issue statements with a squiggly yellow underline.  For some reason, half of my project is underlined.  It's just one solid line that spans almost a hundred lines.  Sometimes it changes position, and where it begins and ends is seemingly random.

Right now, it starts in the middle of a comment block, so that's weird.

Is there any way to get rid of the yellow underline?  It's straining my eyes trying to scan through my code, and I'd rather it disappear entirely and just sacrifice the intended functionality than try and deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no way to turn this off, warnings are useful feedback that you should fix.

If it is hurting your eyes maybe a change of XCode theme would help.

In XCode go to preferences / Font and Colors and select a theme like "midnight" I find that is better on my eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was just mostly concerned with the fact that code that was obviously correct was being erroneously highlighted.  The bug has since disappeared though, I've got my fingers crossed it doesn't return.